# Migrating date into drupal datetime field

Tags: migrations, datetime

i am having the xml selector

```
<starting_date><![CDATA[ 2017-01-01 22:34:56 +0100 ]]></starting_date>
```

this migration process fails :

```
process:
  field_job_starting_date:
    plugin: format_date
    source: starting_date
    from_format: 'Y-m-j H:i:s Z'
    to_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'
    to_timezone: 'Europe/Paris'
```

How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was to import into a drupal datetime field

```
process:
  field_job_starting_date:
    plugin: format_date
    from_format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s O'
    to_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'
    to_timezone: 'UTC'
    source: starting_date
```

https://understanddrupal.com/articles/migrating-dates-drupal

The dates are stored in drupal as UTC